# Re-using generic tasks in Luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I'm having trouble understanding how to make re-usable tasks in Luigi, and then use them in a concrete situation.

For example. I have two generic tasks that do something to a file and then output the result:

```
class GffFilter(luigi.Task):
    "Filters a GFF file to only one feature"
    feature = luigi.Parameter()
    out_file = luigi.Parameter()
    in_file = luigi.Parameter()
    ...

class BgZip(luigi.Task):
    "bgZips a file"
    out_file = luigi.Parameter()
    in_file = luigi.Parameter()
    ...
```

Now, I want a workflow that first filters, then bgzips a specific file using these tasks:

```
class FilterSomeFile(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        return GffFilter(in_file='some.gff3', out_file='some.genes.gff3', filter='gene')

    def output(self):
        return self.inputs()

class BgZipSomeFile(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        filtered = FilterSomeFile()
        BzZip(filtered)
```

But this is awkward. In the first task I have no `run` method, and I'm just using dependencies to use the generic task. Is this correct? Should I be using inheritance here instead?

Then in the second task, I *can't* use dependencies, because I need the output from `FilterSomeFile` in order to use `BgZip`. But using dynamic dependencies seems wrong, because luigi can't build a proper dependency graph.

How *should* I make a Luigi workflow out of my generic tasks?

Answer (score 2):

> But this is awkward. In the first task I have no run method, and I'm just using dependencies to use the generic task. Is this correct?

Yes, according to [this page](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/luigi_patterns.html), the `WrapperTask` is a dummy task whose purpose is to define a workflow of tasks, therefore it doesn't perform any actions by itself. Instead, by defining several requirements, this task will be complete when every requirement, listed in the `requires` method, has been completed. The main difference of this `WrapperTask` to a regular `Task`, is that you don't need to define an output method to signal that this task suceeded, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/bd10d39a284e238ac8021054de96677ff03ced04/luigi/task.py#L800).

> Then in the second task, I can't use dependencies, because I need the output from FilterSomeFile in order to use BgZip. But using dynamic dependencies seems wrong, because luigi can't build a proper dependency graph.

Theoretically, you could make `FilterSomeFile` have the same output as `GffFilter`, make the `BgZipSomeFile` require `FilterSomeFile`, and then use the `FilterSomeFile.output()` in `BgZipSomeFile.run` to access the the zipped file. However, this solution would be somewhat strange because:

- The wrapper task only "runs" 1 other task, so the wrapped task could be used directly, without having to create a `WrapperTask`. A better usage of `WrapperTask` would involve merging `BgZipSomeFile` and `FilterSomeFile` in a single subclass of `WrapperTask`
- A `Task` is being instantiated in a run method. This results in a dynamic dependency, but this is not needed in this problem.
- Finally, the input of `GffFilter` is hardcoded in `FilterSomeFile` task, which makes the workflow less useful. This could be avoided by making the `WrapperClass` still receive parameters, and pass these parameters to its requirements.

A better solution would be:

```
import luigi as lg

class A(lg.Task):
    inFile = lg.Parameter()
    outFile = lg.Parameter()

    def run(self,):
        with open(self.inFile, "r") as oldFile:
            text = oldFile.read()

        text  += "*" * 10 + "\n" + "This text was added by task A.\n" + "*" * 10 + "\n"
        print(text)
        with open(self.outFile, "w") as newFile:
            newFile.write(text)

    def output(self,):
        return lg.LocalTarget(self.outFile)

class B(lg.Task):
    inFile = lg.Parameter()
    outFile = lg.Parameter()

    def run(self,):
        with open(self.inFile, "r") as oldFile:
            text = oldFile.read()

        text  += "*" * 10 + "\n" + "This text was added by task B.\n" + "*" * 10 + "\n"

        with open(self.outFile, "w") as newFile:
            newFile.write(text)

    def output(self,):
        return lg.LocalTarget(self.outFile)

class CustomWorkflow(lg.WrapperTask):
    mainOutFile = lg.Parameter()
    mainInFile = lg.Parameter()
    tempFile = "/tmp/myTempFile.txt"
    def requires(self,):
        return [    A(inFile = self.mainInFile, outFile = self.tempFile),
                    B(inFile = self.tempFile, outFile = self.mainOutFile)
                ]
```

This code can be run in command line with:

```
PYTHONPATH='.' luigi --module pythonModuleContainingTheTasks --local-scheduler CustomWorkflow --mainInFile ./text.txt --mainOutFile ./procText.txt
```

Comment: Task B fails because the myTempFile.txt doesn't exist. It seems there is a race condition between task A and task B. Thanks because I was looking for a confirmation of that.